# Selecting a value in an array in an array; Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, that happens to be filled with arrays: `[[1, "thing"], [2, "other thing"], [3, "still other thing"]]` I want to be able to select a value inside one of the arrays without having to make the array a temporary variable and then pick the item. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index into a nested array with the same '[]' syntax.

```
var arr = [[1, "thing"], [2, "other thing"], [3, "still other thing"]];
console.log(arr[0]); // [1, "thing"]
console.log(arr[0][0]); // 1
```

For reference, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

In that link search for *two-dimensional*

Comment: Oh, that's perfect. I can't believe I hadn't thought of that.